# Alternative to send keys in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I want to send a string to a `textbox` using Selenium, but I find that `sendKeys` is too slow for my liking. If I have a string "abcde", is there any way to send that string as a block instead of typing it out by "a" then "b" then "c" etc via `sendKeys`?

Comment: What WebDriver are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should've added I'm using chrome

Comment: In my experience Chrome always put it in as a block. When I was using the 64 bit IE driver though it was putting each letter at a time. Swapping to 32 bit seemed to resolve it. Maybe try 32 bit version of Chrome?

Comment: slow? hmmm.. selenium put char by char but fast like a copy/paste action

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In python use execute_script

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value='abcde'")
```